# Merge tag from remote git repository without its history

Tags: git, merge

Please consider the following situation:

There are two repositories, one internal for the company's developers and one public (e.g. on GitHub).

```
[public-repo.git]                 [internal-repo.git]
         \                                /    \  \
          \                 (1) pull tag /      \  \
           \                            /        \  \-(developer 2)
            \ (2) push w/o history     /          \
             \                        /            \-(developer n)
              \                      /
            [local copy of public-repo]
```

Now I want to pull a tag (1) "my-tag" from `internal-repo` to my local working copy of `public-repo`. This should then be merged and pushed to `public-repo` (2).

The problem is, that I want to keep the relation with `internal-repo` but do *not* want to make the internal developer history public.

What would be a way to archive this?

What I did so far in my `local copy of public-repo`:

```
git remote add development git@internal-repo.git
git fetch development
git merge -s ours --no-commit my-tag
git commit
```

But this brings the full history of `internal-repo` into `public-repo`.